# Would an access violation in a Windows C++ program crash immediately always?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, access-violation

I have always understood that if you do an access violation in a C++ program(or anything else) in any platform, the violating program would crash immediately. Someone told me that it is not always true in Windows. Is that right? Or would it crash right away always, like I thought it would?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catching access violations on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037202/catching-access-violations-on-windows)

Comment: Accessing the memory, which was not allocated by your program is undefined behavior. And undefined behavior is undefined - potentially anything could happen.

Comment: `program would crash immediately` this is not true. kernel mode handle exception. first, if debugger is connected it ask debugger handle exception with first-chance. if debugger not handle (or not attached) - exception passed to application via `KiUserExecptionDispatcher`. application can handle it via VEH or SEH. if still not handled - exception again sended to debugger(if attached) as last-chance. if still not handled - to process exception port send. and if and here not handled - process terminated

Comment: Access Violations are fairly common, in fact. They're used to dynamically grow the stack. There's a guard page at the end of the stack. When you need that page, because you're calling another function, Windows fixes the Access Violation by allocating extra memory and moving the guard page higher. There can also be other reasons - the common theme is that this is not C++ behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any processor where an access violation causes a mandatory crash.

Access violations are always faults (not traps). The operating system can allow the process to set up an exception handler (invoked from the interrupt vector) that could allow fault to be corrected.

Answer (score -1):

No, and if it did, the worst an adversary could do with a buffer overrun would be a denial of service.

For a specific example, one version of Windows where that is not true is Windows 95, whose memory model was nicknamed The Dangerous Memory Model.  All Win32 programs on that platform get the same selectors, with areas of the memory space reserved for DOS, 32-bit programs, 16-bit programs, and the kernel and drivers, and only an access to the lower part of memory (which NULL pointers reference) will actually crash the program.